# SQL Server data to php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this php script:

```
<?php
$server = 'PCCSAF\SQLEXPRESS';

$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
die('wrong');
}
?>
```

I need to connect to local SQL Server express server, but I always get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\wamp\www\dbgrab\index.php on line 4
```

I've tried to install ntwdblib.dll, uncomment extension=php_ming.dll and extension=php_mssql.dll in php.ini, but it still not works.

I'm using PHP 5.4.3 and WAMP server 2.2 on 64bit windows7

Thank you.

Comment: Did you restart apache after uncommenting those .dll lines?

Comment: This extension has known problems why you shouldn't just use PDO

Comment: Great idea. I installed PDO and the error changed to "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().

Answer (score 2):

WAMP Server x64 is [not compatible with PHP SQL Server Driver](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,74646). Try using 32 bit WAMP.

Comment: Thank you, Jamesking. I reinstalled wamp to 32 bit version, but nothing has changed. I uncomment extension=php_ming.dll and extension=php_mssql.dll. I copied ntwdblib to apache and php folders. Then I check them in "PHP extensions" submenu and restart all services. I can't see this http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_info-mssql.php at my phpinfo() and because of it I can't get it work... Am I missing something? Thank you!